# How can I create a macro which uses a value multiple times, without copying it?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, undefined-behavior, forwarding-reference

I'd like to create a macro which unpacks a pair into two local variables. I'd like to not create a copy of the pair if it's just a variable, which this would accomplish:

```
#define UNPACK_PAIR(V1, V2, PAIR) \
    auto& V1 = PAIR.first; \
    auto& V2 = PAIR.second;

UNPACK_PAIR(one, two, x);
```

However, I'd also like it to not evaluate the expression it's given multiple times, e.g. this should only call `expensive_computation()` once:

```
UNPACK_PAIR(one, two, expensive_computation());
```

If I do:

```
#define UNPACK_PAIR_A(V1, V2, PAIR) \
    auto tmp = PAIR; \
    auto& V1 = tmp.first; \
    auto& V2 = tmp.second;
```

then it works for the `expensive_computation()` case, but it makes a copy in the `x` case. If I do:

```
#define UNPACK_PAIR_R(V1, V2, PAIR) \
    auto& tmp = PAIR; \
    auto& V1 = tmp.first; \
    auto& V2 = tmp.second;
```

Then it works in the `x` case without making a copy but fails in the `expensive_computation()` case. If I do:

```
#define UNPACK_PAIR_CR(V1, V2, PAIR) \
    const auto& tmp = PAIR; \
    auto& V1 = tmp.first; \
    auto& V2 = tmp.second;

#define UNPACK_PAIR_RR(V1, V2, PAIR) \
    auto&& tmp = PAIR; \
    auto& V1 = tmp.first; \
    auto& V2 = tmp.second;
```

These both compile and run, but I suspect they invoke undefined behavior - am I correct about that? Also, would either of these make any sense?

```
#define UNPACK_PAIR_RR(V1, V2, PAIR) \
    auto&& tmp = std::move(PAIR); \
    auto& V1 = tmp.first; \
    auto& V2 = tmp.second;

#define UNPACK_PAIR_RR(V1, V2, PAIR) \
    auto&& tmp = std::forward<decltype(PAIR)>(PAIR); \
    auto& V1 = tmp.first; \
    auto& V2 = tmp.second;
```

---

Is there any way to create a macro that works for both of these use cases - not copying `x` yet also not invoking undefined behavior when given the result of an expression or function call?

Comment: *"These both compile and run, but I suspect they invoke undefined behavior - am I correct about that? "* This depends on the usage. It invokes UB for something like `auto id = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) { return decltype(x)(x); }; auto&& tmp = id(5);`, but it doesn't invoke UB for `auto&& tmp = 5;` -- this has to do with the extension of lifetime of temporaries bound to the reference. Do you **need** to keep the value `V` alive via your macro? `auto tmp = V;` also keeps its value alive, unless it has an internal lifetime issue.

Comment: @dyp: Yes, I'd like to keep the value alive, without making a copy of it (which `auto tmp = V` would do if given a local variable)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431487/c-c-define-macro-inside-macro) might be relevant.

Comment: Sorry, my wording wasn't clear enough. It's obvious that you *need* the value to be *alive*, but it is unclear whether or not the macro has to solve these lifetime issues.

Comment: I really not clear on what you're trying to do. Do you want to obtain a reference to each of the members of a pair? Why? For what? With what constraints? Why a macro?

Comment: What's the use case? Do you want to have better names for the `.first` and `.second` members? Do you want easier access via shorter names?

Comment: @dyp: Easier access via shorter, and more descriptive, names, with minimal typing on my part. e.g. I have `some_vector_variable[the_index]` and I want to use `some_vector_variable[the_index].first` and `some_vector_variable[the_index].second`, I'd like to be able to unpack it only mentioning `some_vector_variable[the_index]` once.

Comment: @Claudiu You write code *one time* and you can even copy paste. And then you make the code explicitly clear by spelling out precisely what you're accessing. Adding extra aliases (variable name indirection) may not make the code any more readable.

Comment: I created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/csaftoiu/ca819edd0e3c73f5ac8e) explaining my reasoning for wanting to do this. Comments are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto&&` creates a forwarding reference, i.e. it accepts anything. It does *not* (always) create an rvalue reference. So just do this:

```
#define UNPACK_PAIR(V1, V2, PAIR) \
    auto&& tmp = PAIR; \
    auto& V1 = tmp.first; \
    auto& V2 = tmp.second;
```

However, I would strongly suggest against this (unless the scope of the use of `UNPACK_PAIR` is very limited and the operation is *really ubiquitous* in that scope). It looks like obscurity for no real benefit to me. Imagine returning to the project after 6 months, with just two hours to find a critical bug. Will you be thanking yourself for using a nonstandard macro-based syntax instead of something readable?

Comment: Note that this can cause lifetime issues for certain corner cases (if `PAIR` is an expression that returns a temporary which doesn't bind directly to `tmp`).

Comment: @dyp Can you describe an example when such a thing would happen?

Comment: See my comment to the OP: `auto id = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) { return decltype(x)(x); }; auto&& tmp = id(5);`. Yes, that's pathological, but it can occur.

Comment: Ah so just to be clear, given something like `std::pair<A, B> get_foo() { return std::make_pair(a, b); }`, if I do `auto&& tmp = get_foo();`, and then I use `tmp`, it doesn't get destructed until say the end of the scope (by default)?

Comment: @Claudiu Yes, the lifetime of that temporary (the return value of `get_foo()`) will be extended.

Comment: This will pollute the current scope with `tmp` ; e.g. using the macro twice in one scope will cause an error.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: True, you have to use a macro which generates a unique re-usable temporary variable (something using `__LINE__`), then it will all work out.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a macro for this.

```
auto p = std::make_pair(2, 3);
int x, y;
std::tie(x, y) = p;
```

If you want references to existing members of a pair:

```
auto p = std::make_pair(2, 3);
auto& x = p.first;
auto& y = p.second;
```

That's it.

Now you can move on to something more challenging/interesting/important.

Comment: Unless the type is not default-constructible.

Comment: I'd like to. Instead of `type_of_first x; type_of_second y; std::tie(x, y) = p;` I'd like to do `UNPACK_PAIR(x, y, p)`. Note how much simpler the macro is, and I don't have to declare any types.

Comment: @Claudiu: Just saying "I'd like to do `UNPACK_PAIR(x, y, p)`" is completely pointless when neither you nor we have any idea what `UNPACK_PAIR` would do. State your actual requirements and constraints.

Comment: @BartoszKP: It is for me, coming from a python background where I can do `x, y = p`. I am essentially trying to mimic that.

Comment: `std::tie(x, y) = p;` looks basically the same as the python to me. What concerns you about that syntax?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yea, I want to get references to existing members of a pair. Yet, given `expression_of_pair`, instead of typing `auto tmp = expression_of_pair; auto& x = tmp.first; auto& y = tmp.second`, I'd like to only have to type `UNPACK_PAIR(x, y, expression_of_pair)`. Maybe not interesting for you, but stylistically for me it makes a difference, hence why I asked.

Comment: @Claudiu I understand, however trying to mimic another language and its idioms leads to bad coding habits, leads to unreadable/unmaintainable code and (as already mentioned) doesn't make sense in general (also, it is impossible in general). Learn the new language instead of trying to "simulate" your favourite one.

Comment: @MarkB: Consider the whole context, though. `type_of_first x; type_of_second y; std::tie(x, y) = p;` does not look like `x, y = p`.

Comment: @Claudiu Why not just wrap this solution into a macro?

Comment: Python doesn't require you to declare variables before using them. C++ does. Thus, it shouldn't be surprising that C++'s tuple unpacking requires you to declare the variables first.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: Right! That's why I asked the question. But I want the macro to not make a copy of the pair. And about the `std::tie` solution, I don't want to make copies of the elements of the pair, either.

Comment: @Claudiu May I ask why you haven't written this particular program in Python since it seems to have all the features you're looking for?

Comment: Wouldn't the equivalent Python code also make copies?

Comment: I think Python references have different semantics from C++ references though. Perhaps what you really need to do to get this to work is to use pointers, rather than references. (Though the solution you have already seems okay.)

Comment: @Claudiu you seem to be very worried about copies. Have you confirmed this is actually a problem? Don't forget that modern compilers are pretty good at optimizing your code. This seems like a real case of premature optimization, at the cost of readability.

Comment: He's forgetting about moves and about RVO and about just about everything else

Comment: @JorenHeit: Well I wanted this macro anyway, because I think it is more readable and easier to code with (others, of course, are free to disagree). I may have worried about copies unnecessarily but ultimately all I had to do was change `auto` to `auto&&` to avoid the issue. Plus in the process I learned more about how forwarding/universal references work. A win overall, I would say.

Comment: @Claudiu: Okay well as long as nobody (including yourself) ever has to work with your code in the future, you're golden. :)

Comment: @Claudiu In this case "others" are very experienced programmers who have made very relevant arguments as to why it is a *bad* idea to use a macro. You should really take this advice seriously and get rid of it. Of course, you are free to disagree, but you'd still be wrong ;-)

Comment: @JorenHeit: Haha. Fair enough. The consensus against is certainly unanimous. My only counter is "well, it's readable to me". The true test of that will be whether I hate myself in six months because of this.

Comment: @JorenHeit: I wrote a little [gist](https://gist.github.com/csaftoiu/ca819edd0e3c73f5ac8e) explaining how I think about these things. Comments are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `std::tie`.

```
decltype(p.first) x;
decltype(p.second) y;
std::tie(x,y) = p;
```

If you want, you could even use that to define your macro. Note that this will only work for 2-tuples - if you want 3-tuples or more, you'll need to do it a bit differently. For example, if you have a 3-tuple `t`:

```
decltype(std::get<0>(t)) x;
decltype(std::get<1>(t)) y;
decltype(std::get<2>(t)) z;
std::tie(x,y,z) = t;
```

Comment: This will copy the values, though (assuming the pair doesn't store references). And it unnecessarily doesn't work with non-default-constructible types. `decltype(p.first)& x = p.first;` etc makes more sense IMO, but that's very close to the (better) `auto& x = p.first;` proposed by others.

Comment: Yeah, the only reason to use `decltype` here would be so you don't have to immediately initialize it. Otherwise `auto` is superior.