# What determines when the lifetimes of temporaries get extended into const references or rvalue references?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue-reference, lifetime

Given:

```
struct hurg { ... };

hurg get_hurg() { return hurg(); }
hurg&& get_mhurg() { return hurg(); }
```

My understanding [and experimenting](https://ideone.com/xcJpqF) shows that the following is *not* undefined behavior (EDIT: thanks to the answers, it turns out I was wrong and the `get_mhurg()` examples *are* undefined behavior):

```
{
    const hurg& a = get_hurg(); 
    hurg&& b = get_hurg();
    const hurg& c = get_mhurg(); 
    hurg&& d = get_mhurg();
    // do stuff with a, b, c, d
}
// a, b, c, d are now destructed
```

That is, the lifetime of the temporary `hurg` object returned by `get_hurg()` and `get_mhurg()` is extended until the end of the scope.

However, in the case of (function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272705/how-can-i-create-a-macro-which-uses-a-value-multiple-times-without-copying-it#comment50539841_31272705)):

```
template <typename T>
auto id(T&& x) -> decltype(auto) { return decltype(x)(x); }
```

Using it like:

```
{
    const hurg& x = id(hurg()); 
    // the hurg() 'x' refers to is already destructed

    hurg&& y = id(hurg());
    // the hurg() 'y' refers to is already destructed

    // undefined behavior: use 'x' and 'y'
}
```

In this case, the lifetime of the `hurg` is *not* extended.

What determines when the lifetime of temporaries is extended in general? And, in particular, when is it safe to bind the result of a function to a const lvalue ref or an rvalue ref?

And more specifically, what precisely is happening in the `id` case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [class.temporary]:

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the fullexpression.
>   The first context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array [...]
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is
>   bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a sub-object to which the reference is bound persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference except:
>   (5.1) — A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion
>   of the *full-expression* containing the call.
>   (5.2) — The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) **is not
>   extended**; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the *full-expression* in the return statement.
>   (5.3) — A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* (5.3.4) persists until the completion of the
>   *full-expression* containing the *new-initializer*.

So two things. First, `get_mhurg` is undefined behavior. The lifetime of the temporary you're returning is **not** extended. Second, the temporary passed into `id` lasts until the end of the full-expression containing the function call, *but no further*. As with `get_mhurg`, the temporary is not through-extended. So that would also be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

> My understanding and experimenting shows that the following is not
>   undefined behavior:

Well, your understanding and experimenting is wrong. Tip for the wise- don't experiment with undefined behaviour. For example, your experiment could randomly happen to indicate that it's well-defined behaviour, which is one of the possible outcomes of undefined behaviour.

Using the return value of `get_mhurg()` is undefined behaviour. You are accessing the temporary `hurg()` outside the scope in which it was created.

The `id` situation just goes to show that lifetime extension is fucking dumb.

Specifically, lifetime extension only applies to *values* directly. It never applies to references of any kind. You must initialize the reference with a value. `id` does not return a value, so no lifetime extension is applied.